# How to install Qt module on perl?

Tags: linux, gui, perl, qt

i want to install perlqt to create a GUI. i see the INSTALL file and it said that a need to install KDE. is really necessary this installation? or just some files.

thanks for you reading.

Answer (score 1):

Which Linux distro are you using?  It is likely pre-packaged for your system.  For example, on my old Fedora box, I could do:

`yum install perl-Qt`

Or on Debian:

`apt-get install libqt-perl`

You could also build it from source directly via Perl with:

`perl -MCPAN -e 'install Qt'`

Or via perl's cpan command, if you have that installed:

`cpan Qt`